# Slider control in XAML-Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, xaml

Is it possible to remove the slider line in the slider control 
(I'm not sure what to call it, but it's the line the slider holder slides to)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to, here are the default styles and templates for the slider control.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278073(v=vs.95).aspx

From [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/silverlight-tutorial-part-7-using-control-templates-to-customize-a-control-s-look-and-feel.aspx) excellent tutorial under the section called Customizing Controls using Control Templates: "The control model used by Silverlight and WPF allows you to go much further than just customizing the inner content of a control. It optionally allows you to completely replace a control's visual tree with anything you want - while still keeping the control behavior intact."

At first I still found this somewhat confusing.  After I watched this 4 part [video series](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/all/building-a-skinnable-custom-control-part-1/) by Jesse Liberty on Building a Skinnable Custom Control this concept of changing a controls look and feel while the behavior remains in tact, made a lot more sense.

Comment: This answer would be improved if you include a sentence or two explaining the templating nature of Controls.  It could well be inferred that Mitc doesn't understand that else why ask the question.